# validation rule on status field when changed from one state to another

Tags: apex

how to  fire/ validation rule when the status field is changed from either open/reopen to some other state.... i am doing field update based on the status change.

```
OR( 
ISCHANGED (Status),ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE (Status), "Open"),
ISCHANGED (Status), ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE (Status), "Reopen")
)
```

This is not firing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
AND(ISCHANGED( Status ),
    OR(
       ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( Status ),"open"),
       ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( Status ),"reopen")
     )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `AND` along with `OR` function.

Try below formula in your validation rule:

```
AND(ISCHANGED( Status ),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status , 'Open'),
        ISPICKVAL(Status , 'Reopen')
    )
)
```

Comment: I am trying to do field update based on the PRIOR status value ::AND ( ISCHANGED (Status), ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE (Status), 'Open')) This will work fine if the status is OPEN, Now i want to add one more condition similar to this when status is 'REOPEN'

Comment: Remove not from my example, edited my example. Or replace OR with AND if that didn't work